# Why can I not get the return type for a Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have an analyzer that needs to examine the return type of a Lambda expression.

In the VS Syntax Visualizer I can right click on a `ParenthesizedLambdaExpression` and click **Show Symbol** and see the correct return type.

I try to replicate this in code as follows:

```
var methodSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(
    lambda,
    context.CancellationToken).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

if (methodSymbol == null)
{
    return;
}

if (methodSymbol.ReturnType != null)
{
    // Never get here! But methodSymbol.IsVoid == false!
}
```

Comment: What's the code snippet you're passing in?

Comment: Also make sure there's no errors in your code. If the compiler can't figure out the type, I'm assuming it just provides `null` as the `ReturnType` and `IsVoid` would still be false.

Comment: Thanks @JoshVarty. It's an embarrassing mistake: the code was failing in a unit test, and I'd missed out a `using` directive.

Comment: No worries, I only know it's a problem because it's a mistake I've made tons of times :)